# Pushing buttons to increase or decrease the same value

Tags: php, html, button

I want to increase the value when i push the first button and if i push the second button to decrease the same value.Here is my code:

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['btn1'])) {
        $_SESSION['clicks'] += 1 ;
        echo  $_SESSION['clicks'];
    } 

    else { if(isset($_POST['btn2'])){

        $_SESSION['click'] = $_SESSION['clicks'] + ($_SESSION['click']- 1) ;
        echo  $_SESSION['click'];
    }
    }
     ?>
   <br><br><br><br>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="+1">
    <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="-1">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure the session is set once before trying to add/subtract from it and use the same session name `clicks` rather than `click` for the subtract I guess.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['clicks'] ) ) $_SESSION['clicks']=0;

    if( isset( $_POST['btn1'] ) ) {
        $_SESSION['clicks']++;
    } elseif( isset( $_POST['btn2'] ) ){
        $_SESSION['clicks']--;
    }
    echo 'clicks: '. $_SESSION['clicks'];
?>




<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="+1">
    <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="-1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare the session variable if it's empty. The reason I changed your code slightly in my example is because it allows the button value to change the variable, which means you don't need to have the if else and it also means that, should you want to, it can be expanded by adding new buttons, such as +2 or -2 without having to change any of the php code, making it more maintainable. Also be careful to use the same variable names. I tend to copy/paste them after first use to cut down on typing mistakes.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(! empty($_POST)) {

    if(empty($_SESSION['click'])) {

        $_SESSION['click'] = 0;
    }

    $_SESSION['click'] += $_POST['btn'];
}

print $_SESSION['click'];
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="+1">
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="-1">
</form>
```

Comment: can you explain why their code failed and what yours does in comparison with what they have now?

Comment: nobody will learn from dropped-in code. RamRaider did that, you could learn from it and provide a better answer. The OP might just like to know why it failed.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry - I just wrote a way of doing it rather than explaining.

Comment: it doesn't work because the session variable is declared each time - thus being overwritten and never storing more clicks - but I didn't downvote btw

Comment: It's only declared if it's empty